# How to print out rows and columns in my React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React with React Boostrap and I'm trying to figure out how I can put three cards on three columns and add a new row every time it reaches three cards. I can't seem to understand how to print out a new Row tag. For what I understand I can't put a conditional wrapped around the  and  tags in a good way. How could I approach this?

```
                 {items &&
                    items.map((item, index) =>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.logo}/>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                                <Card.Text>
                                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                                the card's content.
                                </Card.Text>
                                <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                            </Card.Body>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    )
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it faster and cleaner with  `display: 'grid'` and `gridTemplateColumns:'1fr 1fr 1fr'`.

Yo have to set the parent's `display` to `grid` and with `grid-template-columns` setted with `1fr 1fr 1fr` you'll have a table with 1 fraction of the parent for each one.

Your code will be look like this:

```
<div style={{ display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr 1fr' }} >
    {items && items.map((item, index) =>
        <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.logo} />
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                    the card's content.
                                    </Card.Text>
                <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )}
</div>
```

More info about grid [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using Bootstrap grid.

By putting 3 columns in each row, bootstrap grid will break the column in each new column after the third.

```html
<Row>
  {items &&
    items.map((item, index) =>
        <Col md="4"> // 12 / 4 = 3 columns per row
          <Card>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.logo}/>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title
                  and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                </Card.Text>
                <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
              </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
    )
  }
</Row>
```